# How can I control WiFi in emulators?

Tags: python, wifi, emulation, genymotion

I want to control my WiFi settings (just turning off and on it) in genymotion devices from my python code. Do you have any suggest?
I try it by clicking from navigation menu but I understand that different devices have different WiFi accessibility id!

Answer (score 0):

You can use genyshell with command `genyshell -c "network setprofile no-data"`. See https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/latest/05_Genymotion_Shell.html.

Comment: Thank you Julien for answer. Can I use it when I am work on several devices that in just one of them I want to run this command? Isn't that like adb commands?

Comment: Actually, the solution provided by Julien Bolard is better - what I suggested does not disable Wifi (it just drops 100% of transmission packets). It can be parsed using adb like this: `adb shell svc wifi disable` or `adb shell svc wifi enable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this simple command line to control wifi inside the device:

```
svc wifi enable
```

or

```
svc wifi disable
```